# Flutter - List.builder with different types of items

Tags: flutter

I would like to make a List in Flutter. List consists of more than one type of widget. I made it this way:

```
child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: datasource.length,
    itemBuilder:(context, index) {

      if (datasource[index] == "red") {
        return Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              color: Colors.white,
          ),
        
          height: 80,
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        );
      }

      else {
          return Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              color: Colors.white,
          ),
        
          height: 80,
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        );
      } 
    },
  ),
```

But now I need to add more types of widgets and the code starts to be unclear. Is there any way to move "if else" part to another file?

I have already tried make a method, but failed to import it to original file with List.builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a separate file, let's say widget_helper.dart, and define a function to handle the creation of the containers based on the color.

**In widget_helper.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Widget buildColoredContainer(String color) {
  if (color == "red") {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      height: 80,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    );
  } else {
    // You can add more conditions for other types of widgets here if needed
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      height: 80,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    );
  }
}
```

**And in your original file:**

import 'widget_helper.dart';

```
child: ListView.builder(
  itemCount: datasource.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return buildColoredContainer(datasource[index]);
  },
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Make different class for different type of widget

**widget_list.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class WidgetA extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      height: 80,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Center(child: Text('Widget A')),
    );
  }
}

class WidgetB extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      height: 80,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Center(child: Text('Widget B')),
    );
  }
}

class WidgetC extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        color: Colors.green,
      ),
      height: 80,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Center(child: Text('Widget C')),
    );
  }
}
```

Use the Widgets class in ListView.builder:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class YourListView extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> datasource;

  YourListView({required this.datasource});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: datasource.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final item = datasource[index];

        if (item == "typeA") {
          return WidgetA();
        } else if (item == "typeB") {
          return WidgetB();
        } else if (item == "typeC") {
          return WidgetC();
        } else {
          // Handle other cases or return a default widget
          return Container();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

It is more readable and manageable.

Comment: Isn´t it bad for memory, if there will be about 20 instances of class at once?